# How can iIfix Import "yfinance" could not be resolved

Tags: python, import, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I'm bending reality as we know to try fixing this problem but, apparently, I'm unable to.

I already tried:

`pip install yfinance`

`pip3 install yfinance`

`conda install yfinance`

Reinstalling was tried too, but nothing seems to work.

Already searched in stackOverflow but none of the solutions given helped me =/

Can someone enlight me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the other required packages installed? Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: I simply reformated the PC and it worked haha

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall yfinance package with pip:

`pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir`

https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realized I was running Visual Studio on "restricted mode". Disabling it worked.